# How to test methods in functional component for nextjs components

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library

Component:

```
const Demo = () => {
  const handler = () => {
    // some logic written
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button data-testid={'handler_id'} onClick={() => handler()}>
        Run Handler method
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Demo;
```

test:

```
test('test handler method', () => {
    render(<Demo />)

    act(() => {
        fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('handler_id'));
    });

    // some expectations below
})
```

I am unable to trigger handler method. Even in codeCoverage i dont see this method is covered.
Please help on how to write test cases for methods inside a component. All examples show that the method is passed to component from the props. But here my method is in the component itself.

Comment: That's the right way to trigger the `handler` function in your test. How are you checking that the function has been called?

Comment: No i am not doing anything other than simulating fireEvent on the buttons to check the handler method is triggered or now. But i can't see the code coverage to the handler method.

Comment: And I assume your test isn't failing then? Can you show the output of the code coverage report?

Comment: Yes, Test case is not getting failed. When i use `shallow` from enzyme it works perfectly well. But i got to know that i need to do DOM testing with react testing library. So here comes difficulty in code coverage..